# Boolean property seen as constant

Tags: delphi

I have a custom component, with a `TPersistent` published to the object inspector. This class is filled with boolean properties, such as...

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TPersistent)
  ...
  published
    property SomeBool: Boolean read FSomeBool write SetSomeBool;
  end;
```

Then, elsewhere outside of this component, I'm trying to write to these properties by using a subroutine, accepting a boolean as a `var` parameter:

```
procedure LoadValues;
  procedure CF(var AVal: Boolean);
  begin
    AVal:= False;
  end;
begin
  CF(MyComponent.MyClass.SomeBool);
  // ... repeated on 40 boolean properties in this class
end;
```

The problem is that it fails to compile, telling me:

> E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

I've searched around and cannot find out why. Solutions for other people were along the lines of "Use const, not var". But that completely defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do here. There are 40 Boolean properties in this class, and I'm trying to consolidate assigning these values to just a single line for each.

Why do I get this error, and how do I get around it?

Comment: A `var` parameter requires a variable -- a property cannot be used. The reason is that a pointer is actually passed. If the visibility of `FSomeBool` is high enough, you can do `CF(MyComponent.MyClass.FSomeBool)`, but when this is set, the setter is obviously not called. Also, is your aim merely to initialise all bools to `False`? If so, you can simply do nothing, because class members are always initialized to 0, False, nil, ''.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand D'oh, that should have been common sense. The message was misleading, talking about "Constant object". I found a work-around by making this subroutine a function instead, returning which value to assign to each property. Also, I only set it to `false` as an example, while in reality, I'm reading from somewhere else at that point.

Comment: @JerryDodge You say that you are updating 40 Boolean value properties and in your code you show that these properties do rely on `setter methods`. What do these `setter methods` do? Why I'm asking this? Well if in your `setter methods` you are firing some events to notify that data was changed or do some other code that is updating the state of your component this could lead to lots of additional processing. So perhaps you would want to add a special mechanism to massively update these properties without firing notifications or updating state for each property but doing so only at the end

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for the issue. Note that in reality, I'm not assigning them all to `False` - that was just an example. Really, there's more to specify whether each value should be true or false.

As mentioned in the comments, a `var` parameter (of course) requires a `variable`, whereas a property does not qualify. Rather than trying to pass each property as a var parameter, instead the subroutine could be a function, returning the appropriate boolean value:

```
procedure LoadValues;
  function CF: Boolean;
  begin
    Result:= False; //Or whatever value is needed
  end;
begin
  MyComponent.MyClass.SomeBool:= CF;
  // ... repeated on 40 boolean properties in this class
end;
```